# Correctly Write Test and Callout test on trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, callout, httpcalloutmock

I have a trigger on Account after insert and after update.
In both cases I need to call my BUS to update in the compagny database.
Since I will have to deploy my dev into QA I need to write a test class.

Test the process (trigger -> furturetask -> callout)

Since I am calling my callout with a trigger how do I mock one ? Should I create an entire mock process ? (a test class, a mock trigger, a mock futuretask ?)

The trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {
for(Account account: Trigger.new){
     String jsonObject =  JSON.serializePretty(account);
switch on Trigger.operationType {
    when AFTER_INSERT {
        System.debug('After Insert');
        FutureTaskCreator.createTask(account.Id, 'Insert');
        FutureTaskCreator.sendNotification(''+account.Id, ''+account.Name, jsonObject);
    }
    when AFTER_UPDATE {
        System.debug('After Update');
            // Access the "old" record by its ID in Trigger.oldMap
            Account oldAcc = Trigger.oldMap.get(account.Id);
            Boolean isRecordTypeUpdate = oldAcc.Record_Type__c != account.Record_Type__c;
            Boolean isOnlyAdCloudId = (oldAcc.AdCloud_GroupID__c != account.AdCloud_GroupID__c) || (oldAcc.AdCloud_PartnerID__c != account.AdCloud_PartnerID__c);
            // Before update verify the difference between New and In database
            System.debug('Les Id Account : base account '+ oldAcc.Id + ' parameter ' + account.Id);
            System.debug('En base '+ oldAcc.AdCloud_PartnerID__c + ' et ' + oldAcc.AdCloud_GroupID__c);
            System.debug('A Update '+ account.AdCloud_PartnerID__c + ' et ' + account.AdCloud_GroupID__c);
            // Call the future task method if the trigger isn'nt fired from my external App
            if(!isOnlyAdCloudId && !isRecordTypeUpdate){
                System.debug('Trigger Update');
                FutureTaskCreator.createTask(account.Id, 'Update');
                FutureTaskCreator.sendNotification(''+account.Id, ''+account.Name, jsonObject);
            }
    }
    when else{
        System.debug('Something went wrong');
    }
}
}
}
```

About my booleans : When creating or Updating in SalesForce I need to send the account into my compagny database, once update/inserted I send back to SalesForce my ID's. Doing so It will trigger again the create/update triggers and call again the callout, to avoid that I just check the exitence of the ID's. Whatever.

Here is My callout class :

```
public class FutureTaskCreator {

public static HttpCalloutMock mock = null;
@future(callout=true)
public static void sendNotification(String id, String name, String json_string){
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();
    System.debug('The Json STRING'+json_string);

    String endpoint = 'https://f60146f4.ngrok.io/api/Person';

    /*if (Test.isRunningTest() && (mock!=null)) {
        System.debug('Callout Test');
    }*/
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setbody(json_string);

    try {
        HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }
}

@future(callout=true)
public static void DeleteNotification(String accountId, String recordTypeId){
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();
    String endpoint = 'https://f892d0d3.ngrok.io' ; 

    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('Delete');
    //req.setbody(json_string);

    //req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000
    HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);

}

@future(callout=true)
public static void CreateTask(String recId, String isUpdate){
    Task tsk = new Task();
    tsk.Subject = isUpdate + ' from Future';
    tsk.WhatId = recId;
    insert tsk;
}
```

}

Since I want to deploy It to test I need to create test method. 
Do I need to create a class only for a mock callout ?

My test Method (does not work : 'Methods defined as TestMethod do not support service callouts') :

```
@isTest
private class TestAccountInsertUpdate {
@isTest static void TestInsertAccount() {

    Test.startTest(); 

    System.debug('Inserting ... (single record validation)');
    Account Acc = new Account();
    Acc.Name = 'Account Name';
    Acc.BillingCountry = 'France';
    Database.insert(Acc);
    //insert Acc;

    System.debug('Inserting 200 records... (bulk validation)');

    List<Account> testBulkAccount = new List<Account>();
    for(integer i=0; i<200; i++) {
        testBulkAccount.add( new Account(Name = 'Name'+i, BillingCountry = 'France') );
    }
    insert(testBulkAccount);

    Test.stopTest();
    Account acc1 = [Select Id, Name from Account where Id =: Acc.Id];
    System.assertEquals(acc1.Name,'Test Account');
}
@isTest static void TestUpdateAccount() {
    Test.startTest(); 
    Account Acc = new Account();
    Acc.Name = 'Account Name bis';
    Acc.BillingCountry = 'France';
    System.assertEquals(Acc.Name,'Account Name bis');
    Database.insert(Acc);
    //insert Acc;
    Account acc1 = [Select Id, Name from Account where Id =: Acc.Id];
    acc1.Name ='Account name updated';
    Database.update(acc1);
    //update acc1;
    System.assertEquals(acc1.Name,'Account name updated');
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

}

Now since I am calling my callout with a trigger how do I mock one ?
Shoudl I create an entire mock process ? (a test class, a mock trigger, a mock futuretask ?)

Comment: Please note the syntax is `system.assertEquals(expected_value, observed_value, message)`. You have inverted the order of the first two arguments, and while the third argument is optional, it is strongly recommended as it can provide tremendously helpful context during deployments and other test runs.

Comment: Thank you, I've just begun to use SalesForce. In my test class I do an INsert, how to tell that it should use a mock trigger ?

Comment: Hey @Benoît, I've linked a standard question that includes all the basic resources you need to write and use mocks for testing code with callouts.